# Should I give a second answer if a substantial elaboration is added to the question?

Tags: discussion, answers

If I've answered a question (specifically, [this one](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/32245/have-i-lost-my-daughter)), and it receives an update that adds important elaboration on the situation, how should I handle responding to that new information?

My original answer is *maybe* still relevant (I suspected a mother-daughter issue), but now it seems like a different interpretation (daughter having issues with the extended family in general) is likely. I wish to provide input in light of the new information, but editing my current answer doesn't really make sense - the advice I now want to give is completely different than the original advice I gave.

I could post a new answer, which seems like a sensible way to handle that. Is that reasonable in such situations? I might do that anyway, before heading to bed for the night, but figured it would still be worth asking for general reference.

As for the original answer - what should I do with that one? Leave it in place, maybe with a note redirecting to a new one I post, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't add a new answer. Edit your current answer and add an **Edit to Question Update** clause before you start, especially if the question OP puts something like **Update** in their edit. Adding a new answer muddies the waters and could mislead users who come that don't understand that the question was substantially edited/elaborated upon from it's original posting.